# Is it possible for a DFA to have one state with an empty alphabet?

Tags: automata

I am confused if this is a valid DFA or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That one state must be the initial state. If it is also an acceptor state, the DFA accepts the language $\{\epsilon\}$; if not, the DFA accepts the language $\varnothing$. Both of these are languages over any alphabet, including the empty alphabet.

Comment: Thank you! Can a NFA have one state and an empty alphabet as well?

Comment: @newarsenic: Yes: DFAs are just a special case of NFAs, so every DFA is technically also an NFA. You’re welcome!